# Why doesn't my brain.js LSTM script load from the URL specified in the script tag?

Tags: javascript, brain.js

This is my script:

```html
<script src="http://drwerenverlivitz.atspace.cc/scripts/brain-controller.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <b>Calculator.</b>
  </td>
  <td>
   <b>Bot.</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input id="calculator_input">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="bot_input">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input id="calculator_output" disabled>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="bot_output" disabled>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script>
 render=()=>{
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  try{
   calculator_output.value = eval(calculator_input.value)
   net.train([
    {
     input:calculator_input.value,
     output:eval(calculator_input.value),
    }
   ])
  }catch(e){}
 }
 init=()=>{
  net = new brain.recurrent.LSTM()
  render()
 }
 setTimeout(init,1)
</script>
```

I want to program a bot which learns to calculate any string, like if I say to it 1+1 it answer me 2, or if I say 2*2 it answer me 4, but for do that I need to solve that error. How to do it? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hit that URL in your browser. What happens? Do you see an error in the console? I do. For starters, many sites disallow insecure (non-https) URLs these days.

Comment: yes, try it with https and see the console log from the browser to see the printed error

Comment: Yes, I tried this script without SSL. The script is very laggy after a few seconds, so I want to create a IA which calculates a string, like 1+1 is 2 or 1+2 is 3 or 2*2 is 4...